# Не получается отсортировать данные (msvcp140.i386.pdb не загружен)

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры

Для сортировки данных введены функции int sort() и int sortirovka().
При попытке воспользоваться сортировкой через консоль, появляется следующий баннер:

[image: баннер]

После чего нажимаю "Прервать" и появляется следующее окно:
[image: окно]

Данные для сортировки записываются в текстовый файл с именем TEACHERS, с него же эти данные и считываются.
Отображаются они вот так:
[image: данные для отладки]

Искал проблему в интернете, но подходящего решения я не нашёл.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

using namespace std;

#define SIZELST 100
#define FNAME "TEACHERS.txt"
#define COL 80
#define ROW 20

typedef struct
{
    char fio[50];
    int nompasp;
    int serpasp;
    char adres[50];
    int telefon;
    char discipl[50];
    char kafedra[50];
    char dolzhnost[50];
    char zvanie[50];
    char uchstep[50];
    int stavki;
    int zarpl;
    int stazh;
}

Prepod;
Prepod stud[SIZELST];    // Массив структур
int nst = 0;             // Число введенных структур

                         // ПРОТОТИПЫ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬСКИХ ФУНКЦИЙ

int menu();              // Главное меню
int recording();         // Ввод исходных данных
int displaying();        // Вывод содержимого файла
int searching();         // Поиск по критерию 
int deleting();          // Удаление всех данных из файла
int sort();              // Сортировка


int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "RUS");
    while (true)
    {
        switch (menu())
        {
        case 1: {recording(); break; }
        case 2: {displaying(); break; }
        case 3: {searching(); break; }
        case 4: {deleting(); break; }
        case 5: {sort(); break; }
        case 0: {return 0; break; }
        default: {cout << "\n Выбранный пункт отсутствует!\n"; }
        }
        cout << "\n Нажмите на любую клавишу для продолжения";
        _getch();
        system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}

int menu()               // === МЕНЮ ===
{
    system("color 70");
    cout << "============================================================================================================================\n";
    cout << "======================================= ИНФОРМАЦИОННАЯ СИСТЕМА - ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ =============================================\n";
    cout << "============================================================================================================================\n\n\n";
    cout << "Выберите операцию: \n" << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "1 - ДОБАВИТЬ ИНФОРМАЦИЮ " << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "2 - ПРОСМОТР ВСЕЙ ИНФОРМАЦИИ " << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "3 - ПОИСК ИНФОРМАЦИИ ПО ЗАДАННОМУ КРИТЕРИЮ " << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "4 - УДАЛЕНИЕ ДАННЫХ ИЗ ТЕКСТОВОГО ФАЙЛА " << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "5 - СОРТИРОВКА ДАННЫХ " << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "0 - ВЫХОД " << endl;
    cout << "\n\n==========================================================================\n";
    cout << "============================= ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ КЛАВИШИ 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 0 ==========\n";
    cout << "==============================================================================\n";
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    return i;
}

int recording()          // === ЗАПИСЬ ИНФОРМАЦИИ В ФАЙЛ ===
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    SetConsoleCP(1251); //нужна библиотека Windows.h
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    system("color 70");
    ofstream outFil(FNAME, ofstream::app);

    // ОТКРЫТИЕ ФАЙЛА & ПРОВЕРКА ФАЙЛА НА ОТКРЫТИЕ

    if (!outFil)
    {
        cout << "Файл не открыт!" << FNAME;
        _getch();
        return 1;
    }

    system("cls");
    cout << "\n=============================================== ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ ДАННЫХ В ФАЙЛ ===============================================\n\n\n";
    cout << "Введите число преподавателей: " << endl;
    cin >> nst;
    for (int j = 0; j < nst; j++)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Введите Ф.И.О.: ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].fio, 50);

        cout << "Введите номер паспорта: ";
        cin >> stud[j].nompasp;

        cout << "Введите серию паспорта: ";
        cin >> stud[j].serpasp;

        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Введите адрес: ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].adres, 50);

        cout << "Введите телефон: ";
        cin >> stud[j].telefon;

        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Введите дисциплину: ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].discipl, 50);

        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Введите кафедру: ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].kafedra, 50);

        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Введите должность: ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].dolzhnost, 50);

        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Введите звание: ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].zvanie, 50);

        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Введите учёную степень: ";
        cin.getline(stud[j].uchstep, 50);

        cout << "Введите ставку: ";
        cin >> stud[j].stavki;

        cout << "Введите зарплату: ";
        cin >> stud[j].zarpl;

        cout << "Введите стаж: ";
        cin >> stud[j].stazh;

        cin.ignore();
        outFil << stud[j].fio << " "
            << stud[j].nompasp << " "
            << stud[j].serpasp << " "
            << stud[j].adres << " "
            << stud[j].telefon << " "
            << stud[j].discipl << " "
            << stud[j].kafedra << " "
            << stud[j].dolzhnost << " "
            << stud[j].zvanie << " "
            << stud[j].uchstep << " "
            << stud[j].stavki << " "
            << stud[j].zarpl << " "
            << stud[j].stazh << "\n";
    }
    outFil.close();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int displaying()         // === ВЫВОД ДАННЫХ ИЗ ФАЙЛА НА ЭКРАН ===
{
    system("color 71");
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "RUS");
    string textline;
    char matr[ROW][COL];
    int count = -1;

    // ОТКРЫТИЕ ФАЙЛА & ПРОВЕРКА ФАЙЛА НА ОТКРЫТИЕ

    ifstream inFile(FNAME, ofstream::app);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Файл не открыт!" << FNAME;
        _getch();
        return 1;
    }
    // ВЫВОД СОДЕРЖИМОГО ФАЙЛА НА ЭКРАН & ЧТЕНИЕ ФАЙЛА В МАТРИЦУ

    system("cls");
    cout << "\n============================================= СОДЕРЖИМОЕ ФАЙЛА С ДАННЫМИ ===============================================\n\n\n";
    cout << "                                   ----------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "                                   | Здесь находится вся информация о преподавателях  |\n";
    cout << "                                   | ИНФОРМАЦИОННОЙ СИСТЕМЫ - ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.        |\n";
    cout << "                                   ----------------------------------------------------\n\n";
    while (getline(inFile, textline))
    {
        count++;
        strcpy(matr[count], textline.c_str());
        cout << "\n\n" << matr[count];
    }
    inFile.close();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int searching()
{

    system("color 71");
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "RUS");
    string textline;
    string needle;
    bool founded = false;
    SetConsoleCP(1251); //нужна библиотека Windows.h
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    // ВЫВОД СОДЕРЖИМОГО ФАЙЛА НА ЭКРАН ПО КРИТЕРИЮ & ЧТЕНИЕ ФАЙЛА В МАТРИЦУ

    system("cls");
    ifstream inFile(FNAME);
    cout << "\n======================================================== ПОИСК =========================================================\n\n\n";
    cout << "                                 ----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "                                 | Здесь осуществляется поиск преподавателей по критериям.|\n";
    cout << "                                 | Для этого необходимо вписать критерий и нажать Enter.  |\n";
    cout << "                                 ----------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n";
    cout << "Введите критерий: \n" << endl;
    cin >> needle;
    cout << "\n";

    while (getline(inFile, textline))
    {
        if (textline.find(needle) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << textline << "\n" << endl;
            founded = true;
        }
    }

    if (!founded)
    {
        cout << "Данных по критерию не найдено!" << endl;
    }
    inFile.close();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int deleting()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "RUS");
    system("color 75");
    system("cls");
    ofstream inFile(FNAME, ios::out | ios::trunc);
    cout << "\n================================================= УДАЛЕНИЕ ИНФОРМАЦИИ ==================================================\n\n\n";
    cout << "                       -------------------------------\n";
    cout << "                       |           ВНИМАНИЕ!         |\n";
    cout << "                       | ДАННЫЕ БЫЛИ УСПЕШНО УДАЛЕНЫ |\n";
    cout << "                       -------------------------------\n\n\n";
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    inFile.close();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int sortirovka()
{
    ifstream inFile(FNAME);
    int kolvo_temp = 1;
    string textline;
    do
    {
        inFile.getline(stud[kolvo_temp].fio, 50);
        inFile.getline(stud[kolvo_temp].zvanie, 50);
        inFile.getline(stud[kolvo_temp].kafedra, 50);
        inFile.getline(stud[kolvo_temp].discipl, 50);
        inFile.getline(stud[kolvo_temp].dolzhnost, 50);
        inFile >> stud[kolvo_temp].zarpl;
        inFile.get();
        kolvo_temp++;
    } while (!inFile.eof());
    nst = kolvo_temp - 1;
    return 0;
}

int sort() // сортировка информации и вывод на экран
{
    string needle;
    int vybor;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    string textline;
    int count = -1;
    // Имя открываемого файла, задано в директиве #define
    ifstream inFile(FNAME);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Не открыт файл" << FNAME;
        _getch();
        return 1;
    }
    system("cls");
    cout << "===================ПРОСМОТР ИНФОРМАЦИИ=====================\n";
    cout << " Отсортировать по:" << endl;
    cout << " 1 - УБЫВАНИЮ НОМЕРОВ " << endl;
    cout << " 2 - ВОЗРАСТАНИЮ НОМЕРОВ " << endl;
    cout << " 3 - ЗАРПЛАТЕ" << endl;
    cout << " 0 - ВЫХОД" << endl;
    cin >> vybor;

    if (vybor == 1)
    {
        sortirovka();
        system("cls");
        cout << "===================ПРОСМОТР ИНФОРМАЦИИ=====================";
        cout << "\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
        while (getline(inFile, textline))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= nst; i++)
            {

                cout << "\nНомер: " << i << "| ";
                cout << "Ф.И.О.: " << stud[i].fio << "| ";
                cout << "Звание: " << stud[i].zvanie << "| ";
                cout << "Кафедра: " << stud[i].kafedra << "| ";
                cout << "Дисциплина: " << stud[i].discipl << "| ";
                cout << "Должность: " << stud[i].dolzhnost << "| ";
                cout << "З/П: " << stud[i].zarpl << "| ";
                cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
            }
            _getch();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    else if (vybor == 2)
    {
        sortirovka();
        system("cls");
        cout << "===================ПРОСМОТР ИНФОРМАЦИИ=====================";
        cout << "\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
        while (getline(inFile, textline))
        {
            for (int i = nst; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                cout << "\nНомер: " << i << "| ";
                cout << "Ф.И.О.: " << stud[i].fio << "| ";
                cout << "Звание: " << stud[i].zvanie << "| ";
                cout << "Кафедра: " << stud[i].kafedra << "| ";
                cout << "Дисциплина: " << stud[i].discipl << "| ";
                cout << "Должность: " << stud[i].dolzhnost << "| ";
                cout << "З/П: " << stud[i].zarpl << "| ";
                cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
            }
            _getch();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    else if (vybor == 3)
    {
        sortirovka();
        int temp = 0;
        char* temp2;

        for (int i = 0; i <= nst - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= nst - i - 1; j++) {
                if (stud[j].zarpl > stud[j + 1].zarpl) {

                    temp = stud[j].zarpl;
                    stud[j].zarpl = stud[j + 1].zarpl;
                    stud[j + 1].zarpl = temp;

                    temp2 = stud[j].fio;
                    swap(stud[j].fio, stud[j + 1].fio);

                    temp2 = stud[j].zvanie;
                    swap(stud[j].zvanie, stud[j + 1].zvanie);

                    temp2 = stud[j].kafedra;
                    swap(stud[j].kafedra, stud[j + 1].kafedra);

                    temp2 = stud[j].discipl;
                    swap(stud[j].discipl, stud[j + 1].discipl);

                    temp2 = stud[j].dolzhnost;
                    swap(stud[j].dolzhnost, stud[j + 1].dolzhnost);

                }
            }
        }
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
    inFile.close();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте запустить под отладчиком и посмотреть бэктрейс к месту падения. При следующем запуске остановитесь перед вызовом вашей функции, ниже которой возникает ошибка и внимательно посмсторите на значения всех имеющих отношение к делу переменных (структур данных)

Comment: @avp "... посмотреть бэктрейс к месту падения...", не совсем понимаю, как это делать. объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: Я использую gdb в linux. Насколько вижу, у вас windows и  Visual Studio. Наверное имеет смысл задать отдельный вопрос, как ей пользоваться, чтобы люди обладающие этими знаниями смогли вам конкретно помочь

Comment: Программа упала в библиотеке msvcp от MS, нажимайте на кнопку загрузить символы после чего смотрите стек вызовов. Ищите в нем последний вызов из своего кода и что передавалось в качестве аргументов.

Comment: Код чтения из файла в функции `sortirovka` неверный. Во-первых следует проверять что количество считанных записей не превышает размера массива `stud`, во-вторых помимо `eof()` следует проверять и наличие ошибок при чтении.

Comment: @nevilad а каким образом мне проверить 1 и 2?

Comment: Что такое 1 и 2?

Comment: @nevilad то, что описано в "Во-первых" и "Во-вторых"

Comment: Простейший способ для 1 - сменить `!inFile.eof()` на `!inFile`. По-хорошему проверять надо после каждого чтения, чтобы не сохранять битые записи. Что делать при обнаружении ошибок чтения (предупреждать, отменять все чтение и т.д.) отдельная тема. Для 2 в простейшем случае после `kolvo_temp++;` вставить `if( kolvo_temp >= SIZELST ) break;`, по-хорошему заменить массив на `std::vector`, он будет динамически увеличиваться в зависимости от количества считанных записей.

Comment: @nevilad проблема с вылетом баннера исправилась, спасибо. но теперь появилась другая проблема, когда я выбираю сортировку по зарплате, у меня он просто выводит пустую строку

Comment: Запускайте программу под отладчиком, ставьте точку останова в коде сортировки по зарплате и отлаживайте.

Comment: @nevilad точка останова показала 415 строку: _getch(); Может проблема в том, что для отсортированных данных не хватает команды для их отображения в консоли? Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Не знаю, я не разбираюсь в логике этого кода. Ищите строку которая выводит пустую строку и разбирайтесь почему там не выводится нужное значение.